# I want to send SQL server Dashboard & Health Report to my client on daily basis, so is there ant script / tool to generate report for sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to send SQL server Dashboard & Health Report to my client on daily basis, so is there ant script / tool to generate report for sql server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Performance Dashboard reports and then edit them for use inside reporting services manually, or use them as they are provided.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1d3a4a0d-7e0c-4730-8204-e419218c1efc&displaylang=en

These install the reporting services RDL files to c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Performance Dashboard, and there is a setup.sql script that contains the actual TSQL objects that are used by the reports.  This can easily be the basis for what you are trying to do, and the RDL files can be imported into Reporting Services to allow subscriptions to automate delivery.  There is a known issue with one of them where a datediff using milliseconds overflows the int datatype but you can find a fix to this on Robs blog post:

http://blogs.technet.com/rob/archive/2009/02/18/performance-dashboard-reports-for-sql-server-2008.aspx

You don't really have to do a lot of excess work reinventing the wheel if you start off with the basic Performance Dashboard reports provided by Microsoft with SQL Server 2005 SP2 Feature Pack and then doing small customizations as necessary to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect job for SQL Server Reporting Services.

As to the queries that you need, that will all depend on what you want to show.